# WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=' failed: Invalid frame header

Tags: javascript, node.js

WebSocket connection to `ws://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=k1TmDCaN_RuvTzzVAAAC` failed: Invalid frame header doOpen @ `websocket.js:43` Show 1 more frame Show less

i am expecting why it is not connected two video call

Comment: We can't debug code that isn't shown. Please update your question with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.